# Can't Run html libgdx with libgdx-utils

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx, box2d

Im trying to compile my libgdx game, its working for android and desktop, but not HTML GWT.

Im using Intellij / Gradle for the project.

I just added the `libgdx-utils` extension lib found here which seems to be causing the error: https://bitbucket.org/dermetfan/libgdx-utils/wiki/Dependency%20Instructions

The error i get when attempting this gradle command `./gradlew html:dist` is:

```
:html:compileGwt                 
Compiling module com.xx.xx.GdxDefinition
   Validating units:             
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/xx/xx/xx/screens/GameScreen.java'
         [ERROR] Line 66: No source code is available for type net.dermetfan.gdx.graphics.g2d.Box2DSprite; did you forget to inherit a required module?
   [ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
:html:compileGwt FAILED          

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':html:compileGwt'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

My Gradle file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.5'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13+'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha-04'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'xxx-xxx'
        gdxVersion = '1.4.1'
        roboVMVersion = '1.0.0-alpha-04'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.2'
        ashleyVersion = '1.3.1'
        aiVersion = '1.4.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile 'net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT'
        compile 'net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils-box2d:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' // Box2D module
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

---

Ive made some progress

In my `GdxDefinition.gwt.xml` file i needed to add some `<inheritis>` tags:

```
<inherits name='libgdx-utils' />
<inherits name='libgdx-utils-box2d' />
```

That error is now fixed but now i have about 10000 more errors that are similar

```
Compiling module com.xx/xx/.GdxDefinition
   Validating units:             
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx-backend-gwt/1.4.1/6a7814ff9cedbe7e7576d9578258fa99939fd092/gdx-backend-gwt-1.4.1-sources.jar!/com/badlogic/gwtref/gen/ReflectionCacheSourceCreator.java'
         [ERROR] Line 103: No source code is available for type java.io.PrintWriter; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 701: The method getAnnotation(Class<Retention>) is undefined for the type Class<capture#6-of ?>
         [ERROR] Line 707: The method getCanonicalName() is undefined for the type Class<capture#7-of ?>
         [ERROR] Line 709: No source code is available for type java.lang.reflect.Method; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 709: The method getDeclaredMethods() is undefined for the type Class<capture#8-of ?>
         [ERROR] Line 713: The method getCanonicalName() is undefined for the type Class<capture#10-of ?>
         [ERROR] Line 716: The method getCanonicalName() is undefined for the type Class<capture#12-of ?>
         [ERROR] Line 724: No source code is available for type java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 740: The method getCanonicalName() is undefined for the type Class
         [ERROR] Line 744: The method getCanonicalName() is undefined for the type Class
         [ERROR] Line 747: The method getCanonicalName() is undefined for the type Class<capture#21-of ?>
         [ERROR] Line 748: No source code is available for type java.lang.reflect.Array; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 755: The method getCanonicalName() is undefined for the type Class<capture#23-of ?>
         [ERROR] Line 786: The method getCanonicalName() is undefined for the type Class<capture#33-of ?>
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/xx/xx/xx/screens/GameScreen.java'
         [ERROR] Line 66: No source code is available for type net.dermetfan.gdx.graphics.g2d.Box2DSprite; did you forget to inherit a required module?             
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.6.0/8237d1bd37127188107388c8724be44a0e9f73ca/gwt-user-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/codegen/rebind/GwtCodeGenContext.java'
         [ERROR] Line 52: No source code is available for type java.io.PrintWriter; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.6.0/8237d1bd37127188107388c8724be44a0e9f73ca/gwt-user-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/codegen/server/AbortablePrintWriter.java'
         [ERROR] Line 26: No source code is available for type java.io.PrintWriter; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.6.0/8237d1bd37127188107388c8724be44a0e9f73ca/gwt-user-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/codegen/server/LoggingCodeGenContext.java'
         [ERROR] Line 32: The method getAnonymousLogger() is undefined for the type Logger
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.6.0/8237d1bd37127188107388c8724be44a0e9f73ca/gwt-user-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/codegen/server/SafeHtmlStringGenerator.java'
         [ERROR] Line 29: The method getCanonicalName() is undefined for the type Class<SafeHtmlBuilder>
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.6.0/8237d1bd37127188107388c8724be44a0e9f73ca/gwt-user-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/codegen/server/SourceWriterBase.java'
         [ERROR] Line 63: The method format(String, Object[]) is undefined for the type String
         [ERROR] Line 102: The method format(String, Object[]) is undefined for the type String
         [ERROR] Line 116: The method format(String, Object[]) is undefined for the type String
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/DelegatingGeneratorContext.java'
         [ERROR] Line 49: No source code is available for type java.io.PrintWriter; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/GeneratorContext.java'
         [ERROR] Line 45: No source code is available for type java.io.PrintWriter; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/Linker.java'
         [ERROR] Line 66: The method isAnnotationPresent(Class<Shardable>) is undefined for the type Class<capture#1-of ? extends Linker>
         [ERROR] Line 71: The method getDeclaredField(String) is undefined for the type Class<capture#2-of ? extends Linker>
         [ERROR] Line 73: No source code is available for type java.lang.NoSuchFieldException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/ServletContainerLauncher.java'
         [ERROR] Line 117: No source code is available for type java.net.BindException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/StubGeneratorContext.java'
         [ERROR] Line 40: No source code is available for type java.io.PrintWriter; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/TreeLogger.java'
         [ERROR] Line 50: No source code is available for type java.net.URL; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/debug/JsoEval.java'
         [ERROR] Line 133: No source code is available for type java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 159: No source code is available for type java.lang.reflect.Method; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 159: The method getMethods() is undefined for the type Class<Object>
         [ERROR] Line 175: No source code is available for type java.lang.ClassLoader; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 181: The method getMethods() is undefined for the type Class<capture#2-of ?>
         [ERROR] Line 181: The method getMethods() is undefined for the type Class
         [ERROR] Line 298: The method getClassLoader() is undefined for the type Class<capture#3-of ? extends Object>
         [ERROR] Line 301: The method getClassLoader() is undefined for the type Class
         [ERROR] Line 327: The method forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader) is undefined for the type Class
         [ERROR] Line 339: The method forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader) is undefined for the type Class
         [ERROR] Line 354: The method getMethods() is undefined for the type Class<Object>
         [ERROR] Line 372: The method getMethod(String, Class[]) is undefined for the type Class
         [ERROR] Line 392: The method getMethod(String, Class[]) is undefined for the type Class
         [ERROR] Line 397: The method forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader) is undefined for the type Class
         [ERROR] Line 436: The method isAssignableFrom(Class) is undefined for the type Class
         [ERROR] Line 447: The method isAssignableFrom(Class) is undefined for the type Class
         [ERROR] Line 463: No source code is available for type java.io.PrintWriter; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 464: The method printStackTrace(PrintStream) in the type Throwable is not applicable for the arguments (PrintWriter)
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/Artifact.java'
         [ERROR] Line 49: The method cast(Artifact<capture#6-of ?>) is undefined for the type Class<C>
         [ERROR] Line 76: The method currentThread() is undefined for the type Thread
         [ERROR] Line 77: The method asSubclass(Class<Linker>) is undefined for the type Class<capture#11-of ?>
         [ERROR] Line 99: The method isAnnotationPresent(Class<Transferable>) is undefined for the type Class<capture#14-of ? extends Artifact>
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/ArtifactSet.java'
         [ERROR] Line 89: The method isInstance(Artifact<capture#8-of ?>) is undefined for the type Class<T>
         [ERROR] Line 90: The method cast(Artifact<capture#9-of ?>) is undefined for the type Class<T>
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/GeneratedResource.java'
         [ERROR] Line 45: The method currentThread() is undefined for the type Thread
         [ERROR] Line 46: The method asSubclass(Class<Generator>) is undefined for the type Class<capture#7-of ?>
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/ModuleMetricsArtifact.java'
         [ERROR] Line 36: No source code is available for type java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/SyntheticArtifact.java'
         [ERROR] Line 74: No source code is available for type java.io.ObjectInputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 80: No source code is available for type java.io.ObjectOutputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/impl/JarEntryEmittedArtifact.java'
         [ERROR] Line 37: No source code is available for type java.util.jar.JarFile; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 67: No source code is available for type java.util.jar.JarEntry; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/impl/ResourceInjectionUtil.java'
         [ERROR] Line 139: No source code is available for type java.net.URL; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 143: No source code is available for type java.net.MalformedURLException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/impl/SelectionScriptLinker.j                          ava'                              
         [ERROR] Line 560: No source code is available for type java.net.URL; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 560: The method getResource(String) is undefined for the type Class<SelectionScriptLinker>
         [ERROR] Line 567: No source code is available for type java.net.URLConnection; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/impl/StandardGeneratedResource.java'
         [ERROR] Line 80: No source code is available for type java.io.ObjectInputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 86: No source code is available for type java.io.ObjectOutputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/impl/StandardLinkerContext.java'
         [ERROR] Line 143: The method getAnnotation(Class<LinkerOrder>) is undefined for the type Class<capture#1-of ? extends Linker>
         [ERROR] Line 165: The method getAnnotation(Class<LinkerOrder>) is undefined for the type Class<capture#6-of ? extends Linker>
         [ERROR] Line 528: The method newInstance() is undefined for the type Class<capture#15-of ? extends Linker>
         [ERROR] Line 529: No source code is available for type java.lang.InstantiationException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/impl/StandardSelectionProperty.java'
         [ERROR] Line 76: The method newInstance() is undefined for the type Class<capture#4-of ? extends PropertyProviderGenerator>
         [ERROR] Line 79: No source code is available for type java.lang.InstantiationException; did you forget to inherit a required module?                       
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/impl/StandardSymbolData.java'
         [ERROR] Line 49: The method toURI() is undefined for the type File
         [ERROR] Line 52: No source code is available for type java.net.URI; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 53: No source code is available for type java.net.URISyntaxException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 158: No source code is available for type java.io.ObjectInputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 172: No source code is available for type java.io.InvalidObjectException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 192: No source code is available for type java.io.ObjectOutputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/soyc/SourceMapRecorder.java'
         [ERROR] Line 53: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.thirdparty.debugging.sourcemap.SourceMapGenerator; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 53: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.thirdparty.debugging.sourcemap.SourceMapGeneratorFactory; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 53: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.thirdparty.debugging.sourcemap.SourceMapFormat; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 77: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.thirdparty.debugging.sourcemap.FilePosition; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 82: The method reset() is undefined for the type ByteArrayOutputStream
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/soyc/impl/DependencyRecorder.java'
         [ERROR] Line 82: No source code is available for type java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/soyc/impl/MemberFactory.java'
         [ERROR] Line 77: No source code is available for type java.lang.reflect.Constructor<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 77: The method getConstructor(Class<MemberFactory>, Class<capture#5-of ? super K>) is undefined for the type Class<V>
         [ERROR] Line 85: No source code is available for type java.lang.InstantiationException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 91: No source code is available for type java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/af3d9ad2fb8be30dc87fdcd6d9a373b2ab675802/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/ext/soyc/impl/SizeMapRecorder.java'
         [ERROR] Line 177: No source code is available for type java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

And it just goes on and on like this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT needs the source code to compile. Add this to the HTML project in your build script:

```
compile 'net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils:0.7.2:sources'
compile 'net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils-box2d:0.7.2:sources'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! hmm i have those compile statements in my `core` project, and in the html project i do `compile project(":core")`. Also i think you mistyped the version because I get the following error `Error:Failed to find: net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils:0.7.0`. Did you mean `0.7.0-SNAPSHOT`. I also added `inherits` in the GdxDefinition file is that needed? After doing all that i'm still getting the same error as stated in my question. Any tips?

Comment: There is a slight difference between what you have in the core project's dependencies and what I posted in my reply: I appended `:sources` so that the source files are downloaded instead of the compiled binaries. And sorry, the 0.7.0 release was accidentally skipped. I edited my reply.

Comment: I tried `0.7.3:sources` but its not working unfortunately. `Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':html:compile'. > Could not find net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils:0.7.3.` @dermetfan

Comment: Sorry, I gave you the wrong version _again_... Should be right now. All available versions are listed here: https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~libgdx-utils

Comment: Thanks! ive moved passed that error, now im getting the following error `libgdx-utils-box2d-0.7.2-sources.jar(net/dermetfan/gdx/physics/box2d/Box2DUtils.java):123: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6`. I then tried to change `sourceCompatibility` to 1.7 for `html` and `core` projects and got a different error: `Box2DUtils.java' [ERROR] Line 24: addr cannot be resolved or is not a field`. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this happen on desktop and android as well or is it just the HTML project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64169/discussion-between-dermetfan-and-parampalp).